# Nested List - Question and Answers for a Maths book

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumitem, book-design

I'm trying to set up a maths book in latex. There are excercises in the book and I want to have questions labelled in the form 1 (a) (b) (c) (i) (ii). It's set up in such a way that the answers are entered as a second argument and then the second argument is printed in a solutions file. The answers will be at the end of the book

In the sample code, Q2 should read as follows
Q2
(a)
(b)
(c)
(d) (i)
(ii)
I know there is an issue with the code. Can someone assist me please.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newoutputstream{solutions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}

\newcounter{exblock}
\newcounter{exquestion}
\newcounter{exsubquestion}
\newcounter{exsubpart}

\newlist{questionlist}{enumerate}{3}
\newlist{solutionlist}{enumerate}{3}
\newlist{subquestionlist}{enumerate*}{2}
\newlist{subsolutionlist}{enumerate*}{2}
\newlist{subpartlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\newlist{subpartsolutionlist}{enumerate*}{1}

\setlist[questionlist,solutionlist]{label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[subquestionlist,subsolutionlist]{label=(\alph*),itemjoin={},before=~}
\setlist[subpartlist,subpartsolutionlist]{label=(\roman*),itemjoin={},before=~}


\newcommand{\exheader}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
\refstepcounter{exblock}%
\setcounter{exquestion}{0}%
\section{Exercises}%
\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}}%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\paragraph{Exercises \noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}, page \noexpand\pageref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}}}%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\begin{solutionlist}}%
}

\newcommand{\printsolutions}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutionlist}}}{}%
\closeoutputstream{solutions}%
\input{\jobname.solutions}%
}

\newenvironment{exercises}[1][]{%
\begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
}{%
\end{questionlist}%
}

\newenvironment{exercisescol}[2][]{%
\begin{multicols}{#2}%
    \begin{questionlist}[start=\value{exquestion}+1, #1]%
    }{%
    \end{questionlist}%
\end{multicols}%
}



\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{exquestion}%
\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
\item #1%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.] #2}%
}

\newenvironment{subquestions}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{exquestion}%
\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}%
\setcounter{exsubquestion}{0}%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exquestion}}.]\noexpand\begin{subsolutionlist}}%
    \item #1%
    \begin{subquestionlist}%
    }{%
    \end{subquestionlist}%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{subsolutionlist}}
    }
    
    
\newcommand{\subquestion}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{exsubquestion}%
\item #1%
\addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item #2}%
}

\newenvironment{subparts}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{exsubpart}%
    \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\roman{exsubpart}}
       
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\roman{exsubpart}}.]\noexpand\begin{subpartsolutionlist}}%
        \item #1%
        \begin{subpartlist}%
        }{%
        \end{subpartlist}%
        \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{subpartsolutionlist}}
}

\newcommand{\subpart}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{exsubquestion}%
    \item #1%
    \addtostream{solutions}
}

    \setlist*[questionlist]{font=\bfseries}
    \setlist*[solutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries}
    \setlist*[subquestionlist]{font=\bfseries}
    \setlist*[subsolutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries,itemjoin={\\},before={}}
    \setlist*[subpartlist]{font=\bfseries}
    \setlist*[subpartsolutionlist]{noitemsep,font=\bfseries,itemjoin={\\},before={}}
    
\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}

\exheader
\begin{exercises}
    
        \question{This is a test question}{solution 1}
        
            \begin{subquestions}
            \subquestion{testing1a}{testing answer1} \\
            \subquestion{testing1b}{testing answer2} \\ 
            \subquestion{testing1c}{testing answer3} \\
            
            
            \begin{subparts}
                \subpart{First Sub Part}{First Subpart answer} \\
                \subpart{Second Sub Part}{Second Subpart answer} \\ 
                \subpart{Third Sub Part}{Third Subpart answer} \\
                \end{subparts}

            \subquestion{testing1e}{testing answer3} \\
        \end{subquestions}
        
    
    \begin{subquestions}[Find the range of values of $x$ for which.\\] 
        \subquestion{$3x^2+2x-1\geq0$}{$x\leq-1, \ x\geq\dfrac{1}{3}$} \\
        \subquestion{$x^2+8x-33<0$}{$-11 < x < 3$} \\
        \subquestion{$2x^2-5x+3\le0$}{$1\leq x\leq\dfrac{3}{2}$} \\
    \end{subquestions} \\
    
    \begin{subquestions}[Find the range of values of $x$ for which.\\] 
        \subquestion{$2x^2-3x-2\geq0$}{$x\leq-\dfrac{1}{2}, \ x\geq 2$} \\
        \subquestion{$x^2-6x+8<0$}{$2 < x < 4$} \\
        \subquestion{$x^2+5x+6\le0$}{$-3\leq x\leq -2$} \\
    \end{subquestions}  
    
    \end{exercises}


\chapter{Appendix}

\section{Solutions}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your code is trying to do, but it seems far more complicated than necessary. You are essentially duplicating LaTeX's stepping of counters for no good reason that I can see and, although you're nominally using `enumitem`, you're effectively doing its job manually as well.

The code you posted doesn't compile due to problems with grouping. I tried to track this down but finally abandoned the effort. It was easier to just create a simpler implementation which lets `enumitem` and LaTeX's list handling do most of the heavy lifting.

For the example you posted, we only need a single enumeration environment, `exercises` with three levels. Your code defines 3 but never uses more than 1. In case you want different formatting for the solutions, however, I've created a second nest of three lists `solutions` with exactly the same formatting as `exercises`.

We can configure the formatting of each level of these lists either together or separately. So, for example, we might have

```
\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[exercises]{font=\bfseries}
```

This creates the 3 levels of the list and sets the format of the labels to use bold. All 3 levels in your example use the same font, so it makes sense to set this in one place.

```
% \setlist[exercises,1]{label=\arabic*.}% format in MWE
```

This line would set the format of the labels in the first level to '1.', '2.' etc. Since we don't want that, I've commented it out and replaced it with

```
\setlist[exercises,1]{label=Q\arabic*}% requested format
```

This sets the format to 'Q1', 'Q2' etc.

```
\setlist[exercises,2]{label=(\alph*),noitemsep}
```

For the next level, we set the format of labels to '(a)', '(b)' and kill the separation between items. In your MWE, you tell `enumitem` to create an inline list and then force a line break with `\\`  between items. **Never use `\\`  to end a line** unless you are inside a `tabular`, `array` or similarly special context.

```
\setlist[exercises,3]{label=(\roman*),noitemsep}
```

This line formats the third level of the list in similar fashion.

This eliminates much room for error. We no longer have to manage `\refstepcounter` etc. manually and we have an easy-to-remember set of counter names because `enumitem` names counters after lists. So, when we created the `exercises` list, `enumitem` created three counters for us: `exercisesi`, `exercisesii` and `exercisesiii`. (It did the same for `solutions`, but we don't care about those as we don't intend to use them anyway.

This means we can define `\question`, for example, in a simpler way

```
\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
  \item \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}} #1%
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}}] #2}%
}
```

The only pitfall here is that we need to remember to put `\addtostream` **after** `\item`. In some cases, this means changing the order slightly.

Note that, although I've not done it here, you should probably eliminate `exblock`, too, if it is basically the same as the section counter. However, I wasn't certain whether this was the case in your real document, so I didn't touch this element of the configuration.

[image: typeset exercises with custom numbering]

Not sure if the '2' in the section number here is intentional or whether you want to pick up the section number from earlier, but appendices usually get distinct numbering anyway, so probably this is not something to be determined here in any case.

[image: typeset solutions with custom numbering]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{book}
% ateb https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699706/ i gwestiwn akasteve: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699689/

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
% \usepackage{lipsum}% you cannot need this in your real document and don't use it here

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newoutputstream{solutions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}

\newcounter{exblock}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[exercises]{font=\bfseries}
% \setlist[exercises,1]{label=\arabic*.}% format in MWE
\setlist[exercises,1]{label=Q\arabic*}% requested format
\setlist[exercises,2]{label=(\alph*),noitemsep}
\setlist[exercises,3]{label=(\roman*),noitemsep}

\newlist{solutions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[solutions]{font=\bfseries}
% \setlist[solutions,1]{label=\arabic*.}% format in MWE
\setlist[solutions,1]{label=Q\arabic*}% requested format
\setlist[solutions,2]{label=(\alph*),noitemsep}
\setlist[solutions,3]{label=(\roman*),noitemsep}

\newcommand{\exheader}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{%
    \addtostream{solutions}{%
      \noexpand\end{solutions}%
    }%
  }{}%
  \refstepcounter{exblock}%
  \section{Exercises}%
  \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}}%
  \addtostream{solutions}{%
    \noexpand\paragraph{Exercises \noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}, page \noexpand\pageref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}}%
  }
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\begin{solutions}}%
}

\newcommand{\printsolutions}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutions}}%
  }{}%
  \closeoutputstream{solutions}%
  \input{\jobname.solutions}%
}

\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
  \item \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}} #1%
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}}] #2}%
}

\newenvironment{subquestions}[1][]{%
  \item \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}} #1%
  \addtostream{solutions}{%
    \noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}}]\noexpand\begin{solutions}%
  }%
  \begin{exercises}%
}{%
  \end{exercises}%
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutions}}%
}
    
    
\newcommand{\subquestion}[2]{%
  \item\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}} #1
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}}] #2}%
}

\newenvironment{subparts}[1][]{%
  \item \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}} #1%
  \addtostream{solutions}{%
    \noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}}]\noexpand\begin{solutions}%
  }%
  \begin{exercises}%
}{%
  \end{exercises}%
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutions}}%
}
    
    
\newcommand{\subpart}[2]{%
  \item\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}.\arabic{exercisesiii}} #1
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}.\arabic{exercisesiii}}] #2}%
}

    
\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}

\exheader
\begin{exercises}
  \question{This is a test question}{solution 1}  
  \begin{subquestions}
    \subquestion{testing1a}{testing answer1} 
    \subquestion{testing1b}{testing answer2}  
    \subquestion{testing1c}{testing answer3}     
    \begin{subparts}
      \subpart{First Sub Part}{First Subpart answer} 
      \subpart{Second Sub Part}{Second Subpart answer}  
      \subpart{Third Sub Part}{Third Subpart answer} 
    \end{subparts}    
    \subquestion{testing1e}{testing answer3} 
  \end{subquestions}
  \begin{subquestions}[Find the range of values of $x$ for which.] 
    \subquestion{$3x^2+2x-1\geq0$}{$x\leq-1, \ x\geq\dfrac{1}{3}$} 
    \subquestion{$x^2+8x-33<0$}{$-11 < x < 3$} 
    \subquestion{$2x^2-5x+3\le0$}{$1\leq x\leq\dfrac{3}{2}$} 
  \end{subquestions}   
  \begin{subquestions}[Find the range of values of $x$ for which.] 
    \subquestion{$2x^2-3x-2\geq0$}{$x\leq-\dfrac{1}{2}, \ x\geq 2$} 
    \subquestion{$x^2-6x+8<0$}{$2 < x < 4$} 
    \subquestion{$x^2+5x+6\le0$}{$-3\leq x\leq -2$} 
  \end{subquestions}  
\end{exercises}

\chapter{Appendix}

\section{Solutions}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

### Edit

You can't straightforwardly add Ti*k*Z pictures, say, to the solutions because they are full of things which aren't robust. For simple cases, you can use `\noexpand`. For example,

```
\subquestion{$x^2+5x+6\le0$}{$-3\leq x\leq -2$\noexpand\par
  \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}
    \noexpand\draw [blue, top color=blue, bottom color=blue,middle color=blue!5] circle (50pt);
  \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}}
```

[image: shaded circle in solutions]

For anything more complicated, I'd recommend saving the picture or graph into a box and then simply inserting the box into the solutions.

For example, in the preamble,

```
\newsavebox\mygreencirclebox
```

At the beginning of the document, chapter or whatever,

```
\sbox\mygreencirclebox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [blue, top color=green, bottom color=green,middle color=green!5] circle (50pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

and then

```
    \subquestion{$x^2+5x+6\le0$}{$-3\leq x\leq -2$\noexpand\par
      \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}
        \noexpand\draw [blue, top color=blue, bottom color=blue,middle color=blue!5] circle (50pt);
      \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}%
    \usebox{\mygreencirclebox}}
```

[image: green and blue shaded circles inserted into solutions using different methods]

The box method is much more robust and less error-prone and avoids polluting your code with `\noexpand`.

Comment: I really appreciate this. I've tested your code  and it works exactly how I want it to. The code I submitted is just a small snippet from the actual larger document. Your solution is much simpler. When writing a book like this with many exercises, it becomes difficult to track questions and corresponding answers.

Comment: @akasteve Reinventing the wheel just gets you buggy wheels with sharp angles and straight sides ;).

Comment: Currently the answers are all numerical, but If I needed to include an image as an answer (eg. a simple graph), can this be done?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll do some experimenting.

Comment: @akasteve See edit.

Comment: I'm having a little formatting. There seems to be an overlap with (b) and (i) when I use the folowing \begin{subquestions}
  \begin{subparts}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
  \end{subparts}
  
  \begin{subparts}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
   \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
  \end{subparts}
  
 \end{subquestions}

Comment: @akasteve It works for me: I don't get any overlap when I add that code to the code in my answer. Maybe ask a new question and link this one so you can include a complete example.

Comment: I've posted as a separated question and sent. I pasted it in Overleaf as well and I'm getting the same formatting issue.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707138/nested-list-formatting