# Nested List Formatting

Tags: lists

I'm having a little issue with the formatting of my nested list. There seems to be an overlap with (b) (i) and (c) (i). The formatting in the answers for the same question is fine though. I'm not sure why this is happening. Here is a MWE based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/699706/)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newoutputstream{solutions}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.solutions}{solutions}

\newcounter{exblock}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[exercises]{font=\bfseries}
% \setlist[exercises,1]{label=\arabic*.}% format in MWE
\setlist[exercises,1]{label=Q\arabic*}% requested format
\setlist[exercises,2]{label=(\alph*),noitemsep}
\setlist[exercises,3]{label=(\roman*),noitemsep}

\newlist{solutions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[solutions]{font=\bfseries}
% \setlist[solutions,1]{label=\arabic*.}% format in MWE
\setlist[solutions,1]{label=Q\arabic*}% requested format
\setlist[solutions,2]{label=(\alph*),noitemsep}
\setlist[solutions,3]{label=(\roman*),noitemsep}

\newcommand{\exheader}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{%
    \addtostream{solutions}{%
      \noexpand\end{solutions}%
    }%
  }{}%
  \refstepcounter{exblock}%
  \section{Exercises}%
  \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}}%
  \addtostream{solutions}{%
    \noexpand\paragraph{Exercises \noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}, page \noexpand\pageref{ex.\arabic{exblock}}}%
  }
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\begin{solutions}}%
}

\newcommand{\printsolutions}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{exblock}>0}{%
    \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutions}}%
  }{}%
  \closeoutputstream{solutions}%
  \input{\jobname.solutions}%
}

\newcommand{\question}[2]{%
  \item \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}} #1%
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}}] #2}%
}

\newenvironment{subquestions}[1][]{%
  \item \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}} #1%
  \addtostream{solutions}{%
    \noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}}]\noexpand\begin{solutions}%
  }%
  \begin{exercises}%
}{%
  \end{exercises}%
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutions}}%
}
    
    
\newcommand{\subquestion}[2]{%
  \item\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}} #1
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}}] #2}%
}

\newenvironment{subparts}[1][]{%
  \item \label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}} #1%
  \addtostream{solutions}{%
    \noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}}]\noexpand\begin{solutions}%
  }%
  \begin{exercises}%
}{%
  \end{exercises}%
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\end{solutions}}%
}
    
    
\newcommand{\subpart}[2]{%
  \item\label{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}.\arabic{exercisesiii}} #1
  \addtostream{solutions}{\noexpand\item[\noexpand\ref{ex.\arabic{exblock}.\arabic{exercisesi}.\arabic{exercisesii}.\arabic{exercisesiii}}] #2}%
}

    
\begin{document}


\chapter{First Chapter}

\exheader
\begin{exercises}
  \question{This is a test question}{solution 1}  
  \begin{subquestions}
    \subquestion{testing1a}{testing answer1} 
    \subquestion{testing1b}{testing answer2}  
    \subquestion{testing1c}{testing answer3}     
    \begin{subparts}
      \subpart{First Sub Part}{First Subpart answer} 
      \subpart{Second Sub Part}{Second Subpart answer}  
      \subpart{Third Sub Part}{Third Subpart answer} 
    \end{subparts}    
    \subquestion{testing1e}{testing answer3} 
  \end{subquestions}

    \begin{subquestions}
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
        \end{subparts}
        
        \begin{subparts}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
        \end{subparts}

            \begin{subparts}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
            \subpart{arg1}{arg2}
        \end{subparts}
        
    \end{subquestions}
  
\end{exercises}

\chapter{Appendix}

\section{Solutions}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```